# How to use event.type?

Tags: python, pygame

The program doesn't work when I press the left cursor key. But when I do the conventional way of pygame.keys.get_pressed(), It works. The character moves right, but it doesn't go to the left.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("BALANCE")

def updatedis(x):

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, 480, 40, 20))
    pygame.draw.line(win, (0, 255, 0), (x+20, 480), (x+20, 380), 2)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():

    x = 230
    k = True

    while k:

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                k = False
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x = x-5

        pygame.time.delay(10)

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x <= 460:
            x = x + 5

        updatedis(x)

    pygame.quit()

main()
```

Comment: event inform only that key changed state from `not pressed` to `pressed`. and when it changed from `pressed` to `not pressed`. System doesn't create event when you keep pressed button.

Comment: `pygame.K_LEFT` is NOT `event.type` - `pygame.KEYDOWN` is `event.type` . And `pygame.KEYUP` is `event.type`

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a key is pressed then a single `pygame.KEYDOWN` event occurs. When the key is release then a single `KEYUP` occurs. If you want detect, if the `pygame.K_LEFT` is pressed or released, the you've to check the `.key` attribute of the [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html). Set a state (`left`) when the `pygame.K_LEFT` is pressed and reset the state when it is released.
Change the `x` coordinate in the main loop, when `left` is stated:

```
left = False
while k:

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            k = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                left = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                left = False

    pygame.time.delay(10)

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x <= 460:
        x = x + 5
    if left:
        x = x-5
```

Note, this is very similar to that, what pygame does for you, when stating the values which are returned by [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed).

Comment: Thanks!! I get it now :)